# C# models: One requires namespace other does not

Tags: c#, .net-core, model, namespaces, .net-5

I am building an app with .Net Core/5.

In most cases I have generated models for my Db with a t4 template. However, in some cases I have added models using the add new item => class.  These models appear similar.  However, the ones that I have added manually don't require "Models.". See image below where ParticipatingSchool does not require it.

```
 using MyApp.Models;
```

[image]

Can anyone suggest why?  Models look like this.

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class ClassWeek 
    {
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public Guid Course { get; set; }
        public Guid? Recipe { get; set; }
     }
}


namespace MyApp.Models
{

    public class ParticipatingSchool
    {
        public bool IncludeYN { get; set; }
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

I've tried the obvious.
1/ There are not any duplicate models in the project.
2/ There are not any cases I can find where I have confused namespaces.
3/ In VS I have checked under "edit item properties" context menu and the settings appear the same.

My suspicion is that when a file is created manually in VS it's namespace is tied somehow to the folder it was created in. For the generated models I copy them from the generated folder into the the models folder and change the namespace.
In older versions of .Net I believe that namespaces could be added to web.config or viewImports but not idea how this works in .Net 5 and Razor pages.

Well I tried deleting a generated class file and adding it in new and then putting the code in by hand. But that didn't fix it.

I am now wondering if it's got something to do with the razor page name:

```
namespace MyApp.Pages.ClassWeek
{

    public class ClassWeekListModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<Models.ClassWeek> ClassWeeks { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public List<ParticipatingSchool> Schools { get; set; }
```

It's not a show stopper. The app builds and runs fine. It's just something I'd like to understand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are not lokking like this ... you prolly has `namespace MyApp.Models`  and `namespace SomethingOtherThenMyApp.Models` ... with code that you provide I can't replicate it in Visual Studio ..

Comment: May be you have multiple classes called ClassWeek in different namespaces? In this case you will be forced to specify exact namespace to specify exact class from multiple possible.